# How to use FinalImage variable inside parfor Loop?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am trying to segment an image of (512 x 512) into 4 segments of (128 x 128) images having the upper row of the orignal image. Then trying to run parallel parfor loop on it. But unable to do so. Here is my code.

```
FinalImage = ones(512,512);
%visiblity function initialization, see equation (4)

parfor imageSegment = 1:8;  

     img = double(imread([filename '.jpg']))./255;
     img = im2bw(img);

    if imageSegment == 1
     img = img(1:128,1:128);
    [nrow, ncol] = size(img);
    elseif imageSegment == 2
     img = img(1:128,129:256);
     [nrow, ncol] = size(img);
    elseif imageSegment == 3
     img = img(1:128,257:384);
     [nrow, ncol] = size(img);
    elseif imageSegment == 4
     img = img(1:128,385:512);
     [nrow, ncol] = size(img);

for nMethod = 3:3;

//Some code

end
end

 imwrite(FinalImage, gray(256), [filename '_FinalImage_' num2str(nMethod) '.bmp'], 'bmp');

fprintf('close');
```

How to use FinalImage variable inside the parfor loop ??

Comment: I know you want to replicate the first row in each sub-image, but I'm not quite sure about the dimensions of the final 4 images! Do you want to slice a 512*512 image into 4 sub-images of 512*128? Also, use `imbinarize` instead of `im2bw`, as Matlab does not recommend using it.

Comment: i only want the upper row of the orignal image..4 segments of 128 x 128

Comment: Frankly, I think you don't need to use `parfor` for doing this. I have an i5 CPU and the `for` implementation of the code below took `0.018'`, whereas, the `parfor` took `0.12'` which is way slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract all `16` segments (of size `128*128`) of a `512*512` image in a parallel way, you may want to try the following code:

```
clear;
clc

% #1 image from dataset of standard 512X512 grayscale test images
% Availabe online at http://decsai.ugr.es/cvg/CG/base.htm
img = imbinarize(imread('http://decsai.ugr.es/cvg/CG/images/base/1.gif'));

d = 512; % Needs to be a power of 2
n = 4;   % Needs to be a power of 2
s = d/n;
tmp = zeros(s, s);
ind = 1:s:d;

% parpool(numel(ind))
disp('Process')
tic

parfor i = 1:numel(ind)
    j = ind(mod(i,n)+1);
    for k = 0:n-1
        l = ind(mod(k,n)+1);
        tmp = img(j:j+s-1, l:l+s-1);
        imwrite(tmp,[num2str((i*n)+1+k),'.jpg'])
    end
end

toc
disp('done')
```

The result would be `16` images in the following order:

```
01.jpg | 02.jpg | 03.jpg | 04.jpg
05.jpg | 06.jpg | 07.jpg | 08.jpg
09.jpg | 10.jpg | 11.jpg | 12.jpg
13.jpg | 14.jpg | 15.jpg | 16.jpg
```

I wrote the program in a parametric way i.e. you can input any image of `2^m*2^m` and ask for any number of segments `n = 2^q` where `m` and `q` are arbitrary numbers.

The `imread` opening online images is slow, you may want to have your images on disk. Also, you can uncomment the `parpool` to change the number of workers, if you're on a HPC cluster.

Comment: how to get all the 16 segments ?? 128 x 128 size

Comment: @Waleed Ansari, I changed the answer to extract all 16 segments. Hope this time works for you!